# Privlege error trying to create symlink using python on windows 10

Tags: python, windows, symlink

I am attempting to create a symlink using python on windows 10 (home version) with the foll. code:

```
import ctypes

kdll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll")
kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkW(src_dir, dst_dir, 1)
```

but I get the foll. error:

```
*** error: (1314, 'CreateSymbolicLink', 'A required privilege is not held by the client.')
```

How to fix this?

Comment: If UAC is enabled and your user is an administrator, then you have to elevate (i.e. "run as administrator") to get the unrestricted administrator token that has `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`.

Comment: thanks @eryksun, I do have admin privledges, but how do I do what you are suggesting? If you can put it as an answer, I will be happy to accept it

Comment: Windows-X, A will open an admin command-line window.  If you run your Python program from there it should work.

Comment: thanks @eryksun, doesn't mklink not need elevation as well?

Comment: I am using python 2.7 (a library needs it)

Comment: cmd would need to be elevated to have `mklink` create a symbolic link, but not a junction -- e.g. `subprocess.call('mklink /J "%s" "%s"' % (link, target), shell=True)`.

Comment: it works!! thanks!!! plz write it as an answer so i can accept

Comment: By the way, you don't have to call `CreateSymbolicLinkW` manually - you can use `os.symlink` (on Python 3).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If UAC is enabled and your user is an administrator, then the Local Security Authority (LSA, hosted in lsass.exe) logs your user on with a restricted access token. For this token, the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group is used only for denying access; the integrity-level label is medium instead of high; and the privileges typically granted to an administrator have been filtered out.

To create a symbolic link, you need to create the process using your unrestricted/elevated access token (i.e. elevated from medium to high integrity level). Do this by right-clicking and selecting "Run as administrator". This elevated token will be inherited by child processes, so it suffices to run your Python script from an elevated command prompt, which you can open via the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Win+X</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>. You can verify that the cmd shell is elevated by running `whoami /priv` and checking for the presence of `SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`. Don't be alarmed if the state is disabled. The Windows [`CreateSymbolicLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363866) function automatically enables this privilege.

That said, since you're creating a *directory* symbolic link, then perhaps a junction will work just as well. No special privilege is required to create a junction. You can create a junction using cmd's `mklink` command. For example:

```
subprocess.check_call('mklink /J "%s" "%s"' % (link, target), shell=True)
```

Answer (score 12):

https://www.scivision.dev/windows-symbolic-link-permission-enable/

1. Open gpedit.msc
2. Computer Configuration → Windows Settings → Security Settings → Local Policies → User Rights Assignment → Create symbolic links

   Type the user name and click “Check Names” then OK.
3. Reboot the computer

Answer (score 5):

These days, the easiest way to make it possible to create Symbolic Links is to enable Developer Mode.

Go to `Settings > Privacy & Security > For Developers` and turn `Developer Mode` to `on`. Immediately, it should be possible to create symbolic links.